# WebMatrix Helper controlled table showing wrong time in Password Change Date field

Tags: c#, database, date, passwords, webmatrix

everyone,

I have a quick question.  Can anyone tell me why the field "PasswordChangeDate" in the helper controlled table "webpages_Membership" (automatically filled using the Web.Security Helper, I'm pretty sure) is logging a date/time that is 5 hours off?  I just changed my password and looked at the field and saw that while I had changed my password at 10:50 AM, it showed 3:50 PM.  Is there a setting somewhere (possibly for time zone, etc.) that I need to adjust within the Web.Security helper?  One thing I do know is that when I go to the "Site" section in WebMatrix, in the "Request" tab, it IS in fact showing the correct timestamps for my requests here.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SimpleMembership Provider uses UTC DateTimes, so presumably your time zone is UTC - 5 (or somewhere on the eastern side of the USA). You can either implement your own Membership Provider and override all the methods that insert a DateTime value into the membership database, or convert the stored time to one of your preferred time zone using the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx) method.

What you can do if it is important for you to display the local time that a user registered or changed their password is to ask them what time zone they are in when they register. You can then store the offset form UTC as part of their profile, and use that with the DateTime.AddHours method to calculate the time in their time zone.

Comment: Do you have any example of the code you would use if you were in, say, central standard time.  The thing I'm not sure of here is that, if I put this into code, is this something that is going to need to be run every time a Session starts for a user (do I need to use _AppStart file) or is it something that, once the code is executed on the server, it is done (kind of like creating roles, where you check if they are created and if not, create them)

Comment: The link I posted in my reply shows an example of converting from UTC to another timezone. I have updated my answer with an easier approach to managing this.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, the link color on my computer is so very much like the regular text color. Didn't see it there. Thnx!