# Saved date and time is different with current time zone, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, timezone

I noticed that the application run in my development machine save a different date and time  with my current timezone. The date and time is saved automatically by the application (not entered by the user).
How to fix that? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

FYI: The table is webpages_Membership

Comment: Fix what? Normally date/time values stored in UTC, so value being different from current time is expected - I'd be really surprised to see exact match (unless you are in UTC timezone).

Comment: by storing the data in the database as UTC, you avoid many of the potential pitfalls involved with time zones and daylight savings time, as the time is in a universally accepted standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it appears that the application is writing the datetime to the database as UTC time. When read and displayed, the application converts it back to your local time zone .

You probably don't want to change this behavior. Check out this questions for more information: [WebMatrix Helper controlled table showing wrong time in Password Change Date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090475/webmatrix-helper-controlled-table-showing-wrong-time-in-password-change-date-fie)

Comment: IC. Thank you very much for the explanation. I haven't display it yet, because I still struggle to access the simpleidentity table from the linq.